# CurrentTimeMillis changing, any possible reason?

Tags: java

when System.currentTimeMillis changed, what will be the possible reason?

say the currentTimeMillis changed 1 and 2 minutes hour only after 2 minutes. Related to day light saving?

One possible reason is the time is synced to the correct time , what will be the other possible reason?

Comment: I'd *expect* `currentTimeMillis()` to change pretty regularly... you know, to stay *current*. Presumably you have a different sort of change in mind - perhaps you could tell us what?

Comment: Uh, it's later than it used to be?

Comment: What do you mean changed - it will change always - it is the underlying clock time. If you call it multiple times you will get different results.

Comment: The currentTimeMillis changed from say 6:00 to 7:02 after only 2 minutes

Comment: @user705414: `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a `long`. If you're logging 6:00 somewhere, then clearly there's been a conversion - and that conversion may well be applying daylight saving time etc. Please don't make us drag each detail out of you - read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and update the question so that it's actually answerable...

Comment: @Jon, I am always using UTC to convert long to 8601 format

Comment: @user705414: Did you read the page I linked to? You haven't taken action on it, otherwise I'd be able to see all the relevant code in the question...

Comment: The code is quite simple, I found two successive reads of currentTimeMills differs nearly an hour suddently in some machine

Comment: This could happen if you have problems with NTP.  When the clock is updated with NTP, it will slowly correct the time which is reflected in currentTimeMillis (but not nanoTime) This means it can jump forward or backward, usually by milli-seconds but in theory second, minutes, hours is also possible.

Comment: @user705414: *You say* it's quite simple, and yet you're refusing to post it. Why? There could easily be a simple mistake in there, but you're basically preventing us from helping you by refusing to post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()`, according to its documentation, returns the *the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.* So obviously it's changing rapidly all the time. The caveat is that it refers to wall clock, which could be adjusted anytime!

That is, it will jump <strike>an hour because of [daylight saving time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)</strike> an arbitrary amount if someone or something - possibly an automated NTP synchronizer - simply adjusts the computer's clock or date. If you need to measure how long something takes, you should use a *timer*, e.g. `System.nanoTime()`, which is guaranteed to change monotonically, not a clock (which is *supposed* but not *guaranteed* to refer to some fixed point).

Comment: As it is measured in UTC, it is *not* affected by daylight savings time.

Comment: @Joona, could you let me know what do you mean occasionally.

Comment: @Joona, do you mean I have to use NanoTime rather than CurrentTimeMillis

Comment: @user705414: Yes. Use `System.nanoTime()`, and more precisely, difference between successive `System.nanoTime()` readings: it's guaranteed to be ascending as long as the difference is less than 292 years (after which the difference overflows). `currentTimeMillis()` is affected by wall clock and thus doesn't offer such monotonicity guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

I will just begin guessing - mainly I see  2 possible reasons:

- You are writing the conversion from milliseconds since 01.01.1970 00:00UTC by yourself and did somwhere a mistake (we going to need the code)
- There is some point when actually the return value makes a jump of 3600000 (such jumps will only happen if you change the System clock, or maybe you update the time using NTP)